# See all output from commands performed inside screen

Tags: linux, bash, console, minecraft, more

I am using screen (http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) to access my minecraft console.  I created a server in `/etc/init.d`, and have minecraft running in the background.

Then, to access the minecraft console, I just type # `screen -r` in bash.

I can now do commands in the screen shell.  The problem is if I do some command which exports a bunch of text, it exceeds the size of the screen and pushes the begging output off the page.  And I cannot seem to scroll up and see it.

How can I scroll back and view all the output?  How can I pause the output (maybe something like `more` or `less`)?

Comment: Alt+PageUp and Alt+PageDown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

- `Ctr-a [` and move up and down with the arrow keys, `esc` for exit.
- `<commamd> | less` if you are in a regular bash terminal

Comment: Thanks Agomezl.  Not a regular bash terminal, but screen.  Ctr-a seems to be much used with screen, so I expect you are pointing me in the right direction.  When trying control-a, I can do things like "d" to detach the screen, but the up and down arrow keys have no effect.

Comment: is `ctr-a + [` (note the open bracket) to enter in copy/scrollback mode, that should allow you move up and down with the arrow keys, and as I said esc for exit to regular mode.

Comment: right on on the [.  How should I have known that if not told by you?  I did look at the screen documentation, but didn't see it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-A ?   To get help.

CTRL-A ESC PGUP

Whether uppercase A or lowercase a depends on your system.